# Selection Sort random average case is lower than expected

Tags: java, sorting

The the worst case of insertion sort with 2,000 array elements is 4,000,000 exchanges and the best case is 0 exchanges. Why am I getting around 4,000 exchanges as the average case with a randomly sorted array? Shouldn't it fluctuate between 0 and 4,000,000?

I am recording the # of comparisons and the # of exchanges for the algorithm with a various sort functions.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class SortAlgorithm
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int sort1[] = new int[2000];//sorted
        int sort2[] = new int[2000];//reverse sorted
        int sort3[] = new int[2000];//random sorted
        Random rand = new Random();
        String str;
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Colin\\Desktop\\Test.txt"));


        for(int i = 0; i < sort1.length; i++) //sorted
        {
            sort1[i] = i;
        }
        str = "Bubble Sort in sorted order: ";
        str += bubbleSort(sort1);
        writer.write(str);
        writer.newLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < sort1.length; i++) //sorted
        {
            sort1[i] = i;
        }
        str = "Selection Sort in sorted order: ";
        str += selectionSort(sort1);
        writer.write(str);
        writer.newLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < sort1.length; i++) //sorted
        {
            sort1[i] = i;
        }
        str = "Insertion Sort in sorted order: ";
        str += insertionSort(sort1);
        writer.write(str);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.newLine();





        for(int i = 0, j = sort2.length - 1; i < sort2.length; i++, j--)//reverse sorted
        {
            sort2[i] = j;
        }
        str = "Bubble Sort in reverse sorted order: ";
        str += bubbleSort(sort2);
        writer.write(str);
        writer.newLine();
        for(int i = 0, j = sort2.length - 1; i < sort2.length; i++, j--)//reverse sorted
        {
            sort2[i] = j;
        }
        str = "Selection Sort in reverse sorted order: ";
        str += selectionSort(sort2);
        writer.write(str);
        writer.newLine();
        for(int i = 0, j = sort2.length - 1; i < sort2.length; i++, j--)//reverse sorted
        {
            sort2[i] = j;
        }
        str = "Insertion Sort in reverse sorted order: ";
        str += insertionSort(sort2);
        writer.write(str);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.newLine();





        for(int i = 0; i < sort3.length; i++)//random sorted
        {
            sort3[i] = rand.nextInt(2000) + 1;
        }
        str = "Bubble Sort in random sorted order: ";
        str += bubbleSort(sort3);
        writer.write(str);
        writer.newLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < sort3.length; i++)//random sorted
        {
            sort3[i] = rand.nextInt(2000) + 1;
        }
        str = "Selection Sort in random sorted order: ";
        str += selectionSort(sort3);
        writer.write(str);
        writer.newLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < sort3.length; i++)//random sorted
        {
            sort3[i] = rand.nextInt(2000) + 1;
        }
        str = "Insertion Sort in random sorted order: ";
        str += insertionSort(sort3);
        writer.write(str);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.close();
    }

    static String selectionSort(int sort[])
    {
        int comparisons = 0, exchanges = 0;
        String str;
        int n = sort.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int small = sort[i];
            int pos = i;
            comparisons++;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                comparisons++;
                if(sort[j] < small)
                {
                    small = sort[j];
                    pos = j;
                    exchanges++;
                }
                comparisons++;
            }

            int temp = sort[pos];
            sort[pos] = sort[i];
            sort[i] = temp;

        }
        str = "Number of comparisons: " + (comparisons) + " , number of exchanges: " + (exchanges);
        return str;
    }

    static String insertionSort(int sort[])
    {
        int comparisons = 0, exchanges = 0;
        String str = "";
        int n = sort.length;
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            int j = i - 1;
            int temp = sort[i];
            comparisons++;
            while(j >= 0 && temp < sort[j])
            {
                sort[j + 1] = sort[j];
                j--;
                exchanges++;
            }
            sort[j + 1] = temp;
            comparisons++;
        }
        str = "Number of comparisons: " + (comparisons) + " , number of exchanges: " + (exchanges);
        return str;
    }

    static String bubbleSort(int sort[])
    {
        String str;
        int comparisons = 0, exchanges = 0;
        int n = sort.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            comparisons++;
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            {
                comparisons++;
                if (sort[j] > sort[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = sort[j];
                    sort[j] = sort[j + 1];
                    sort[j + 1] = temp;
                    exchanges++;
                }
                comparisons++;
            }
        }
        str = "Number of comparisons: " + (comparisons) + " , number of exchanges: " + (exchanges);
        return str;
    }
}
```

here is the output:

```
Bubble Sort in sorted order: Number of comparisons: 4000000 , number of exchanges: 0
Selection Sort in sorted order: Number of comparisons: 4000000 , number of exchanges: 0
Insertion Sort in sorted order: Number of comparisons: 3998 , number of exchanges: 0

Bubble Sort in reverse sorted order: Number of comparisons: 4000000 , number of exchanges: 1999000
Selection Sort in reverse sorted order: Number of comparisons: 4000000 , number of exchanges: 1000000
Insertion Sort in reverse sorted order: Number of comparisons: 3998 , number of exchanges: 1999000

Bubble Sort in random sorted order: Number of comparisons: 4000000 , number of exchanges: 1005056
Selection Sort in random sorted order: Number of comparisons: 4000000 , number of exchanges: 11590
Insertion Sort in random sorted order: Number of comparisons: 3998 , number of exchanges: 970272
```

Comment: If you want to find out average number of exchange operations for these algorithms, you must execute your program many times (say, 1 000 000 times) and then find the average. From the output it seems you ran it just once.

Comment: I ran it a few times and the random sorted order keeps coming out to around 3,900. Shouldn't it be randomly between 0 and 4,000,000?

Comment: You create arrays of 2000 elements, but your random numbers are only in range [1-10]. In other words, you have many, many same numbers in the arrays.

Comment: That was a mistake, I changed it back to 2,000 elements, but now it is gravitating around 11,000 exchanges, yet the reverse sorted algorithm has 4,000,000 exchanges... it still doesn't seem plausible to have the random  sort vary so little